# Machine learning - Algorithm suggestion for my problem using NLP

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, text-mining, vector-space-models

I am looking for a machine learning algorithm for my problem.

I have a set of sentences like,

`["The cat in the hat disabled", "A cat is a fine pet ponies.", "Dogs and cats make good pets.","I haven't got a hat."]`

and the search-words like,

`["cat","hat"]`

I want to convert my sentence list and search-words to a vector space and find matching score between my sentence list and search-word list.

the type of output I am expecting is,

`[("The cat in the hat disabled",0.9), ("A cat is a fine pet ponies.",0.5), "(Dogs and cats make good pets.",0.6),("I haven't got a hat.",0.49)]`

Please suggest a machine learning algorithm for my task, if possible please share a reference link.

let me know if you have any queries or need more information.
I am currently using semanticpy for this https://github.com/josephwilk/semanticpy

I am getting key-error for many search-words. its not performing stemming and lemmatization for the sentence list but only performing for the search-words list.

Please help on this.

Comment: you need to refer to the following [link](http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/) . I think this is the exact thing you seek.

Comment: Is fuzzy-wuzzy finds similarity in vector space representation?

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiKMIuYidY0&index=5&list=PLd1QJ09bWBCIL_e1W-GqfT0OG18KReGWp&t=8244s) about this topic from a PyCon in 2016. There is a pretty in-depth description on how to vectorize your sentences as well as make predictions based on those vectors.

I think that would greatly help you out. That is what I used when I was learning about how to perform sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a proper task for [Doc2Vec](https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf), which is an algorithm to build paragraph embeddings. For a nice implementation with usage examples you can try out [gensim](https://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial/).

Other options can be using [word2vec](https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/) and using vector averaging or sum to build sentence vectors (look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234310/doc2vec-worse-than-mean-or-sum-of-word2vec-vectors)).

For more approaches have a look at these two tutorials where you can see how to implement LSA, LDA, TFIDF:

https://nlpforhackers.io/topic-modeling/

https://medium.com/mlreview/topic-modeling-with-scikit-learn-e80d33668730

Answer (score 1):

**You need to do fit_transform first then transform, Here sample example**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer


train_set = ["president of India","machine learning is awesome", "python is awesome", "thanks for reading"]

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix_train = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set)
tfidf_matrix_test = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(["president"])

print(cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix_train,tfidf_matrix_test))
```